# How to Type Juggle in PHP 8.0?

Tags: php

Understanding [Type Juggling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) in PHP 8.0 is confusing. The documentation above states no changes to PHP 8.0 with type juggling operators. Take this example:

```
# Payload: { 'token': 0 }

$payload = json_decode(json_encode(array('token' => 0)));
$token   = 'RaNdOmStRiNg1!';

echo "[PAYLOAD] " . gettype($payload->token) . "({$payload->token}) - ";
echo "[TOKEN] {{$token}} - ";

if($token != $payload->token) {
    die('Access Denied');
}

echo 'Access Granted: Type Juggling Bypass';
```

If we execute this over at [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/ckEqm), we can see that in PHP 8.0 the `!=` is treated like `!==` whereas in > 8.0, Type Juggling occurs.

My current applications use PHP 8.0, to this end, is using the `==` and `!==` operators when parsing JSON now safe? Is this an intended update to PHP? How would one now specify to Type Juggle where required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [simpler test case](https://3v4l.org/DhpZA):

```
var_dump(0 == 'Kittens');
```

This change is documented in the [Backward Incompatible Changes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php) section of the PHP/8 release notes:

> Non-strict comparisons between numbers and non-numeric strings now work by casting the number to string and comparing the strings. Comparisons between numbers and numeric strings continue to work as before. Notably, this means that 0 == "not-a-number" is considered false now.

Comment: Therefore casting is required to invoke Type Juggling. This makes sense and is probably best practice either way. Many thanks!

Comment: Rather than being a specific feature, I understand Type Juggling as the name of the documentation section that explains the rules to handle comparisons among different types. The change in PHP/8 illustrated by your code is that comparing against zero isn't as dumb as it used to.

Comment: Yeah. I think Strict Type has progressively become a PHP standard over the versions which ideally makes more sense and is much easier to write maintainable code with. PHP is known for its soft typed syntax but moving to use more data types is a good thing IMO as you’re right, it makes it less “dumb” - thanks for the additional comment, it cleared up my understanding that it really isn’t a “feature” but more of a comparison handling technique